# How should I store eggs in the refrigerator?

Tags: storage-method

We just bought a new refrigerator, and it came with the obligatory open egg tray container, which went promptly into the recycle bin--which got me thinking.  I have never understood the purpose of this accessory, as I keep my eggs stored in the original carton.

What is the best way to store fresh eggs in the refrigerator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Keeping Food Fresh](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062725033) by Janet Bailey says:

> Keep stored eggs covered. Eggs readily absorb odors from, and lose
>   moisture to, the air circulating in the refrigerator. The best
>   container for them is the carton you bought them in. Don't use the
>   open egg racks in the door of the refrigerator. The rack is too warm
>   and unprotected.
>
> Store eggs with their broad, rounded ends up. This position helps the
>   chalaza keep the yolk centered in the white, away from the air pocket
>   where it might encounter unfriendly bacteria. The rounded end of the
>   egg is also less likely to break when accidentally bumped.
>
> Don't wash eggs before you store them. If they have been coated in
>   oil, you would be washing away that valuable protection.

Comment: Strangely, that is at least the fourth time today I have seen (or used) the word "chalaza".

Comment: If they're less likely to break *and* safer with the rounded end up, why are they universally in the cartons with the rounded end down?

Comment: @Kareeen perhaps it's a conspiracy by egg farms to get us to by more eggs.

Comment: @Jolenealaska This is known as the [Baader-Meinhof phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baader-Meinhof_phenomenon). It's oddly common.

Answer (score 1):

I wrap the egg cartons in doubled supermarket plastic bags, tie them shut, and store them in the back of the refrigerator.  They will keep for several weeks like this, and they will not lose moisture or take on any unwanted odors.

Comment: That sounds incredibly inconvenient. I would never use them if that were the case.

Comment: @moscafj : if you're buying multiple cartons of eggs at a time, you only need to have one convenient at a given time.  I could see doing this with all but one of the cartons in my fridge.

Comment: @Joe perhaps you are correct.  I don't have a need to have more than a dozen or two at a time.  Even so, anything wrapped, tied or hidden in my fridge is less likely to get used in a timely manner.  ...could just be me.

Answer (score 0):

I simple would not bother and use that space for other stuff.

The best way to store is in box, each morning as you pass them turn the box over as this will help keep the yolk in the middle of the eggs!  I have heard that this is method used when on boats and they can last for many weeks using this method.

Always use "smell by date" (I am going to get this put on my grave, family of six and we have learnt to throw away next to nothing).